# How to make url dynamic in formula field

Tags: formula

Good day,

could somebody please help me how to adjust this formula and to make url to be dynamic, not hardcoded?

HYPERLINK("https://bginc--devyopo2.lightning.force.com/" & Id, bgi_Quote_Name__c)

Answer (score 0):

To make your url dynamic used the template strings.
example:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/products/${id}`

The id here will render different product id in a new page

Comment: My question is how to make https://bginc--devyopo2.lightning.force.com/ to be dynamic. The reason is that when I transfer this field to another org, I have to change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me
HYPERLINK(LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_530, FIND( '/services', $Api.Partner_Server_URL_530))&'/'& Id,bgi_Quote_Name__c)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).